# Django error: render_to_response() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context_instance'

Tags: python, django

After upgrading to Django 1.10, I get the error `render_to_response() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context_instance'`.

My view is as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def my_view(request):
    context = {'foo': 'bar'}
    return render_to_response('my_template.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback:

File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django110/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django110/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django110/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/alasdair/dev/rtr/rtr/urls.py" in my_view
  26.     return render_to_response('my_template.html', context,  context_instance=RequestContext(request))

 Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: render_to_response() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context_instance'
```

Answer (score 142, accepted):

The `context_instance` parameter in `render_to_response` was [deprecated in Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.8/#dictionary-and-context-instance-arguments-of-rendering-functions), and removed in Django 1.10.

The solution is to switch to the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render) shortcut, which automatically uses a `RequestContext`.

Update your imports and view as follows. Note that `render` takes the `request` object as its first argument.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    context = {'foo': 'bar'}
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', context)
```

The `render` shortcut was introduced in Django 1.3, so this change is compatible with older versions of Django.

Answer (score 2):

in Django 1.8 is compatible:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def my_view(request):
    context = {'foo': 'bar'}
    return render_to_response('my_template.html', {'context':context}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

in Django 1.11

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import RequestContext

def my_view(request):
    context = {'foo': 'bar'}
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', context)
```

Comment: You don’t have to use `render_to_response` in Django 1.8. As I say in my answer, the `render` version works in Django 1.3+.

Comment: In django 1.8 also is compatible with: render_to_response, checked for me in a virtualenv. Nevertheless in last versions of django is with render.

Comment: Yes, `render_to_response` works in 1.8, but there's no good reason to use it - `render` is simpler.

Comment: There's a mistake in your `render_to_response` example. Just use `context`, not `{'context': context}`.

Answer (score 0):

**Django 2.0.7 python 3.5**

**in project/urls.py**

```
handler404 = 'project.views.not_found'
handler500 = 'project.views.server_error'
```

**in project/views.py**

```
def not_found(request, exception=None):
response = render(request, '404.html', {})
response.status_code = 404
return response

def server_error(request, exception=None):
response = render(request, '500.html', {})
response.status_code = 500
return response
```

exception=None is passed because otherwise it throws **TypeError: server_error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'exception'**

Comment: I'm not sure why you added this as an answer to this question, it doesn't appear to have anything to do with `render_to_response`.