# Django CSRF Error for Registration

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I've thoroughly searched and applied code to the best of my current ability fixes to what solved other peoples similar problems, except I still get a 403 CSRF error when the user presses 'register' on my registration form, but admin login works. If any one can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

The things Ive tried and checked so far is: to put the CSRF middleware at the top of the middleware list, make sure the html registration form has `{% csrf_token %}`, make sure the register view contains `render_to_response` with `RequestContext`, and now im at a loss of what to try next.

My project is called **mysite**, with the app **login**.

Using django 1.10.5 and python 3.5


***mysite/urls.py:***

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from login.views import home, logout_page, register_success, register
import django
from django.contrib.auth import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^webapp/', include('webapp.urls')),
    #url(r'^', include('personal.urls')),
    url(r'^contact/', include('personal.urls')),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^$', django.contrib.auth.views.login),
    url(r'^home/$', home),
    url(r'^register/$', register),
    url(r'^register/success/$', register_success),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', django.contrib.auth.views.login),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout_page),
]
```

***mysite/settings.py:***

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'webapp',
    'personal',
    'blog',
    'login',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

import django.contrib.auth
django.contrib.auth.LOGIN_URL = '/'


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

***login/views.py:***

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from login.forms import *
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext

@csrf_protect
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
            password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
            email=form.cleaned_data['email']
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/success/')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
    'form': form
    })

    return render_to_response(
    'registration/register.html',
    variables,
    )
    #return render_to_response("registration/register.html", {'form': form}, RequestContext(request))

def register_success(request):
    return render_to_response(
    'registration/success.html',
    )

def logout_page(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

@login_required
def home(request):
    return render_to_response(
    'home.html',
    { 'user': request.user }
)
```

***login/templates/registration/register.html:***

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>User Registration</h1>
<form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
    <table border="0">
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <button type="submit" value="Register">Register</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='/' ">Login</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

## Update

[Django error: render_to_response() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context_instance'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739422/django-error-render-to-response-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-context-i)

The above solved the problem via me changing the view.py to:

```
return render(request,
'registration/register.html', {'form':form},
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass `context_instance` parameter to  `render_to_response` function:

```
return render_to_response(
    'registration/register.html',
    variables,
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
)
```

**UPDATE:**
In new versions of django use `render` instead of `render_to_response`, this issue not raising.

Comment: Your code didn't work, but it helped me to this post thanks!! :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739422/django-error-render-to-response-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-context-i
In which it solved the error, ill put the solution as an update on the question

Comment: @jupiar, i glad its helped you, i update my answer :)