# Django and python TypeError

Tags: python, node.js, django, typeerror

I can access the admin area of the website but i cant get to homepage and other front end pages..following error pops up...

```
> TypeError at / render_to_response() got an unexpected keyword argument
> 'context_instance' Request Method:    GET Request
> URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Django Version:  1.10.6 Exception
> Type: TypeError Exception Value:   render_to_response() got an
> unexpected keyword argument 'context_instance' Exception
> Location: C:\Users\DEEP\Desktop\Bus_reservation\src\bus\views.py in
> index, line 10 Python Executable: C:\Python34\python.exe Python
> Version:  3.4.4 Python Path:  
> ['C:\\Users\\DEEP\\Desktop\\Bus_reservation\\src', 
> 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python34.zip',  'C:\\Python34\\DLLs', 
> 'C:\\Python34\\lib',  'C:\\Python34', 
> 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Here is TRACEBACK

```
> Environment:
> 
> 
> Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
> 
> Django Version: 1.10.6 Python Version: 3.4.4 Installed Applications:
> ['bus.apps.BusConfig',  'bookTicket.apps.BookticketConfig', 
> 'account.apps.AccountConfig',  'django.contrib.admin', 
> 'django.contrib.auth',  'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
> 'django.contrib.sessions',  'django.contrib.messages', 
> 'django.contrib.staticfiles'] Installed Middleware:
> ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
> 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
> 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
> 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
> 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
> 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware', 
> 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
> 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
> 
> 
> 
> Traceback:
> 
> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
> in inner
>   42.             response = get_response(request)
> 
> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
> _legacy_get_response
>   249.             response = self._get_response(request)
> 
> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
> _get_response
>   187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
> 
> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
> _get_response
>   185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
> 
> File "C:\Users\DEEP\Desktop\Bus_reservation\src\bus\views.py" in index
>   10.     return render_to_response(template_name,locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
> 
> Exception Type: TypeError at / Exception Value: render_to_response()
> got an unexpected keyword argument 'context_instance'
```

Here is my file views.py--BUS

```
> from django.shortcuts import render_to_response from django.http
> import HttpResponse from django.template import RequestContext from
> .models import BusInfo,BusDropArea,BusPickArea
> 
> import json
> 
> def index (request, template_name ='bus_resrv_system.html'):
>     page_title = 'Bus'
>     return render_to_response(template_name,locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
> 
> def search_bus(request,template_name ='bus/search_bus.html'):
>     page_title = 'Book a ticket'
>     
>     if request.method == 'POST':
>         post_data = request.POST.copy()
>         area_from_id = post_data.get('area_from_id')
>         area_to_id = post_data.get('area_to_id') 
>         bus_info_list= BusInfo.objects.filter(arriving_from_id=area_from_id,depature_at_id=area_to_id)
>     return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
> 
> 
> def autocomplete_pick(request):
>     if request.is_ajax():
>         q = request.GET.get('term', '')
>         drugs = BusPickArea.objects.filter(area_name__icontains = q )[:20]
>         results = []
>         for drug in drugs:
>             drug_json = {}
>             drug_json['id'] = drug.id
>             drug_json['label'] = drug.area_name
>             drug_json['value'] = drug.area_name
>             results.append(drug_json)
>         data = json.dumps(results) 
>     else:
>         data = 'fail'
>     mimetype = 'application/json'
>     return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
> 
> def autocomplete_drop(request):
>     if request.is_ajax():
>         q = request.GET.get('term', '')
>         drugs = BusDropArea.objects.filter(area_name__icontains = q )[:20]
>         results = []
>         for drug in drugs:
>             drug_json = {}
>             drug_json['id'] = drug.id
>             drug_json['label'] = drug.area_name
>             drug_json['value'] = drug.area_name
>             results.append(drug_json)
>         data = json.dumps(results) 
>     else:
>         data = 'fail'
>     mimetype = 'application/json'
>     return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

In addition to solving the error,i have also change the render_to_response method to render..as per old Django libraries issues..but then NameError pops up for undefined render!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django error: render\_to\_response() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context\_instance'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739422/django-error-render-to-response-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-context-i)

Answer (score 0):

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) on how to call `render_to_response`. With newer versions of django, the signature is:

```
render_to_response(template_name, context=None, content_type=None, status=None, using=None)
```

You are passing `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` which is not a valid argument... What version of django are you using?

Comment: Django Version: 1.10.6    Python Version: 3.4.4