# django 1.11.6 csrf_token value is null?

Tags: python, django, csrf

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

**myview.py**

```
@csrf_protect #ensure_csrf_cookie....etc i tried it.
def category(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    dic = {
        'a': 'aaaa',
        'b': 'bbb'
    }
    return render_to_response('cate.html', dic, context_instance=context)
```

**cate.html**

```
<form name="cateForm" id="cateForm" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="href" id="href" size="50">
</form>
```

and I html view source then csrf_token value is null.

Answer (score 2):

Don’t use `render_to_response`, it’s obsolete. Use `render` instead.

```
def category(request):
    dic = {
        'a': 'aaaa',
        'b': 'bbb'
    }
    return render(request, 'cate.html', dic)
```

Answer (score 0):

context_instance parameter of render_to_response function is deprecated and was removed in Django 1.10. The problem was discussed here: [Django error: render_to_response() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context_instance'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739422/django-error-render-to-response-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-context-i).