# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Tags: python, django

[image]

I'm trying to upgrade a django project from 1.8 to 1.10. Following: [Django error: render_to_response() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context_instance'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739422/django-error-render-to-response-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-context-i)

I have changed a view function from

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from sellmyland.settings import DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
from ipware.ip import get_ip
import json
from myapp.forms import myform


def index(request):


    form = myform()

    # return render('longform.html', {"form": form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    return render(request,'longform.html',RequestContext())
```

You can see the commented out version in the code. I'm getting the error above. Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback:

File "....\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "....\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "....\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "....\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "....myapp\views.py" in index
  31.     return render(request,'longform.html',RequestContext())

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

How can I get this working?

EDIT:

I tried changing to both:

```
return render(request,'longform.html', RequestContext(request, {'form': form}))
```

and

```
return render(request,'longform.html', {'form': form})
```

However in both cases I'm getting:

```
Template loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine :
    This engine did not provide a list of tried templates.



Traceback:

File "....\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "....\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "....\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "....\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "E:\ENVS\r3\sellmyland3\app1\views.py" in index
  31.     return render(request,'longform.html', RequestContext(request, {'form': form}))

File "....\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "....\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  67.         template = get_template(template_name, using=using)

File "....\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in get_template
  25.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /
Exception Value: longform.html
```

Any ideas?

edit2:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))  


TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

edit3:

TypeError: dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

edit4:

```
ERRORS:
?: (admin.E402) 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth' must be in TEMPLATES in order to use the admin application.

WARNINGS:
?: (1_8.W001) The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in Django 1.8 and the TEMPLATES dictionary takes precedence. You must put the values of the following settings into your default TEMPLATES dict: TEMPLATE_DEBUG.

System check identified 2 issues (0 silenced).
```

last edit:

I got it working by using:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': DEBUG,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is `RequestContext` class. It has required argument `request`. But you don't need to pass `RequestContext` as `render` argument. Just use `dict` instead:

```
return render(request, 'longform.html', {"form": form})
```

Comment: It's worth updating the answer to explain that the `RequestContext()` is what's complaining about it having no `request` object passed to it.

Comment: @user61629 where are your templates located? You should add template directory to TEMPLATE's DIR setting: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/#configuration

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the `request` to `RequestContext()` that's why it's giving error. Check out the doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext).

```
def index(request):

    form = myform()
    return render(request, 'longform.html', RequestContext(request, {'form': form}))
```

It's better to use a `dict` rather than `RequestContext()`. For that you can do this.

```
def index(request):

    form = myform()
    return render(request, 'longform.html', {'form': form})
```

EDIT:

Add these to your `settings.py`.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            # some options
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: @user61629 Show us your template setting in `settings.py`. Did you add `templates` to `DIRS` ??

Comment: ERRORS:
?: (admin.E402) 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth' must be in TEMPLATES in order to use the admin application.

WARNINGS:
?: (1_8.W001) The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in Django 1.8 and the TEMPLATES dictionary takes precedence. You must put the values of the following settings into your default TEMPLATES dict: TEMPLATE_DEBUG.

System check identified 2 issues (0 silenced).

Comment: @user61629 remove the context processors from options, I've updated my answer. and pass a `dict` to render instead of `RequestContext()`.