# How to call django forms inlineformset into django templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

i am new to django and learning some from stackoverflow. Now i am creating a website for post with images and title. I found ways to connect my two models (images and post) at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62158885/13403211. it is working fine when i add post from admin. But i want to know how can i add those inlineformset fields into my template for user to fill in.Does anyone knows??
Here is the code i found. I copy the same code in my app to try.

models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="items")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class ItemImage(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    img = models.ImageField(default="store/default_noitem.jpg", upload_to=get_image_dir)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory

from .models import Item, ItemImage

class  ItemImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ItemImage
        exclude = ()

class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ["name",]

ItemImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Item, ItemImage, form=ItemImageForm,
    fields=['img'], extra=3, can_delete=True  # <- place where you can enter the nr of img
)
```

views.py

```
class ItemCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = "items/add_item_form.html"
    success_message = 'Item successfully added!'
    form_class = ItemForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(ItemCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data['form_images'] = ItemImageFormSet()
        if self.request.POST:
            data['form_images'] = ItemImageFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        else:
            data['form_images'] = ItemImageFormSet()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        form_img = context['form_images']
        with transaction.atomic():
            form.instance.user = self.request.user
            self.object = form.save()
            if form_img.is_valid():
                form_img.instance = self.object
                form_img.save()
        return super(ItemCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

I have search on google and i did not find any related to this. Or am i doing wrong? Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi can someone answer me please. I need this for my assignment pleasee

Comment: what exactly goes wrong in your case?

Comment: nothing wrong i just want to know how can i add field from ItemImageFormSet into my templates so that user can insert and upload

Comment: i want a form with username and image how can i get this form?