# Try to Upload Several Pictures, but only 1 is getting saved

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to allow user to upload several pictures, but only one picture is saving to the database. This is my Model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class File(models.Model):
    files = models.FileField(upload_to='images/')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='files')
```

next, the form for the upload looks like this:

```
from django import forms
from .models import File


class FileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=File
        fields=('files',)
        widgets={'files':forms.FileInput(attrs={'id':'files','required':True,'multiple':True})}
```

finally, the view 'upload pics' is the following:

```
def upload_pics(request, user_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
    form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    files = request.FILES.getlist('file_field')
    if form.is_valid():
        pics = form.save(commit=False)
        pics.user = request.user
        pics.files = request.FILES[files]
        return redirect("groups:index")

else:
    form = FileForm()
    render(request, 'accounts/account_form.html', {'form':form})
return render(request, 'accounts/account_form.html', {'form':form})
```

the problem is that only 1 picture is being saved. any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, but it seems like what you are looking for is Django [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/). It will allow you to upload multiple images at once. Also take a look at the answer to this question: [how to upload multiple images to a blog post in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006994/how-to-upload-multiple-images-to-a-blog-post-in-django)