# How to implement multiple image upload for an instance of a model in Django admin

Tags: python, django, file-upload

Hi there i am  building an ecommerce site and would like my items to have alternative images but for this to happen i need to implement upload of multiple image files for each item in admin, How can i go about this? my current model just has the normal ImageField implementation

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    price = models.FloatField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pdt_imgs/')
    sku = models.IntegerField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60961015/13290801

Comment: Thanks but this is an implementation on the client side im looking at working with this in django admin