# Django form is valid() returns false

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I  am trying to do multiple file uploads in Django but am encountering some errors: form.is_valid() returning false. <br>
I have tried printing form.erorrs and it gives me the following:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>uploaded_images<ul class="errorlist"><li>“b&#x27;\xbd\x06D\xcd3\x91\x85,\xdf\xa5K\n&#x27;” is not a valid value.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

I am not sure how to interpret this general error. Been searching for quite some time but couldn't find an answer.

Edit: 
Im also encountering a "This field is required." error 
Perhaps this screenshot may help with debugging:
[image]

I must be missing something simple but I just can't find it!!
Another pair of eyes to help me sieve through would be very appreciated!

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from .forms import BRForm
from .models import *

class BRHomeView(FormView):
    form_class = BRForm
    model = TargetImage
    template_name = 'br/br-home.html'
    context_object_name = 'bankrecon'

    def get(self, request):
        form = BRForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'title': 'Bank Reconcilation'})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('uploaded_images')
        print("POST")
        print(request.POST)
        print("FILES")
        print(request.FILES)
        print(form.errors)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        return redirect('br-home')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class UploadedImages(models.Model):
    image_files = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/')

class TargetImage(models.Model):
    invoice_date = models.DateTimeField()
    recon_date = models.DateTimeField()
    uploaded_images = models.ManyToManyField(UploadedImages)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.invoice_date
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator
from .models import *

class BRForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TargetImage
        fields = ('invoice_date', 'recon_date', 'uploaded_images')
        widgets = {
            'invoice_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
            'recon_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
            'uploaded_images': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True, 'accept':'.jpeg, .png, .jpg'}),
        }
```

relevant template code:

```
<div class="mt-5 d-flex justify-content-center">
  <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <button class="btn btn-success mt-3" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Extra info: My request.POST and request.FILES seems to be working fine:

```
POST
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['hiding this'], 'invoice_date': ['2021-02-01'], 'recon_date': ['2021-02-01']}>
FILES
<MultiValueDict: {'uploaded_images': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: first_slide (1).jpg (image/jpeg)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: fourth_slide (1).jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>
```

Thank you all!!

Comment: show template code

Comment: Have added! Please have a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this issue! <br>
Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60961015/10732211 <br>

I overhauled the entire thing and followed the above link. Probably the models relations have some issues that does not work. <br>

views.py

```
class BRHomeView(FormView):
    # model = TargetImage
    template_name = 'br/br-home.html'
    context_object_name = 'bankrecon'

    def get(self, request):
        form = BRFormExtended()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'title': 'Bank Reconcilation'})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = BRFormExtended(request.POST,request.FILES)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('image_files')

        if form.is_valid():
            print("Form Valid")
            print(form.cleaned_data['invoice_date'])
            print(form.cleaned_data['recon_date'])

            user = request.user
            invoice_date = form.cleaned_data['invoice_date']
            recon_date = form.cleaned_data['recon_date']
            target_image_obj = TargetImage.objects.create(user=user,invoice_date=invoice_date, recon_date=recon_date)
            for file in files:
                UploadedImage.objects.create(target_image=target_image_obj,image_files=file)
        else:
            print("Form Invalid")
        return redirect('br-home')
```

forms.py

```
class BRForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TargetImage
        fields = ['invoice_date', 'recon_date']
        widgets = {
            'invoice_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
            'recon_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        }

class BRFormExtended(BRForm):
    image_files = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))

    class Meta(BRForm.Meta):
        fields = BRForm.Meta.fields + ['image_files',]
```

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone

class TargetImage(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    uploaded_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    invoice_date = models.DateTimeField()
    recon_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.__str__()

class UploadedImage(models.Model):
    target_image = models.ForeignKey(TargetImage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image_files = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/')
```

Also, it would  be helpful to have a media root folder and edits to urls.py is also required.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import BRHomeView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('', BRHomeView.as_view(), name='br-home'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
```

Hopefully this will help someone!

Answer (score 1):

Some errors that I see in your code:

- You're trying to render a POST request in your `get` method.
- You're not passing any data from POST request to your form instance. That's why `is_valid()` is returning `False`.

Change your code to something like this and see if it works:

```py
...
    def get(self, request):
        form = BRForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'title': 'Bank Reconcilation'})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = BRForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        return redirect('br-home')
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out those errors!
I see what you mean! Let me try!

Comment: I have tried your answer and unfortunately, gave the following when i print:
POST
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['hidden'], 'invoice_date': ['2021-02-01'], 'recon_date': ['2021-02-01']}>
FILES
<MultiValueDict: {'uploaded_images': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: first_slide (1).jpg (image/jpeg)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: fourth_slide (1).jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>
<ul class="errorlist"><li>uploaded_images<ul class="errorlist"><li>“b&#x27;fN\r&#x27;” is not a valid value.</li></ul></li></ul>