# How to make post form like twitter in django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

It is very simple to create a post form which takes text, images and gif, but I need to make it dynamic like twitter. twitter can take number of images at once and can display them line by line as the user posted them (ordered).

Answer (score 0):

For back-end this is an apt solution to store multiple images linked to single user:
[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006994/how-to-upload-multiple-images-to-a-blog-post-in-django)

For front-end you can just add the multiple property for file type.
[For reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp)