# How to Update multiple Images in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I was looking for a feature for uploading multiple images and found this solution [how to upload multiple images to a blog post in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006994/how-to-upload-multiple-images-to-a-blog-post-in-django)

but that method doesn't provide any explanation about updating those multiple images like image can be removed and added new one. how to update multiple images?

Comment: every image should have own ID and you should send all IDs which you want to delete - and you could use these IDs in loop to delete every image separatelly. I think you could use `<form>` with many `checkbox` to send many `IDs` to django